# MATLAB: How to dynamically access variables

Tags: matlab, variables, dynamic, eval

I declared some variables comprising of simple row vectors which represents input parameters for another function. Within a loop these variables should be used and the result will be assigned to a structure.

Now, my question is how to best access the content of the predefined variables. I found a solution using `eval`. However, I often read that the usage of `eval` should be avoided. Apparently it's not best practice. So, what's best practice for my problem?

```
varABC = [1,2,3];
varDEF = [4,5,6];
varGHI = [7,8,9];

names = {'ABC','DEF','GHI'};

result = {'result1','result2','result3'};

for i = 1 : 3
    varString = strcat('var',names{i});
    test.(result{i}) = sum(eval(varString));
end
```

Comment: The best practice is to avoid dynamic variable names

Comment: Or as [Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14343/ned-batchelder) so aptly put it: [_Keep data out of your variable names_](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). _Any time this happens, it's a clear sign that you need to move up a level in your data modeling_

Comment: `bigVar = [varABC; varDEF; varGHI];` or `bigVar = {varABC; varDEF; varGHI};`. Then you just have to loop over the indices.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, this is helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting your code a little bit

```
names = {'ABC','DEF','GHI'};
result = {'result1','result2','result3'};
```

**option 1**

```
% Use struct instead of a simple variable
var.ABC = [1,2,3];
var.DEF = [4,5,6];
var.GHI = [7,8,9];

for i = 1 : 3
    test.(result{i}) = sum(var.(names{i}));
end
```

**option 2**

```
% Use dictionary
c = containers.Map;
c('ABC') = [1,2,3];
c('DEF') = [4,5,6];
c('GHI') = [7,8,9];

for i = 1 : 3
    test.(result{i}) = sum(c(names{i}));
end
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing the containers.Map class. I haven't been aware of its existence.